# Spring get all queries params as a string

Tags: spring

I have an API gateway that handles all GET requests and forwards them to the correct url like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> doGet(HttpServletRequest req) {

        String uriString = (String) req.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

       String targetHost = uriString.split("/")[0];
       URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(targetHost)
           .path(uriString)
           .build().normalize().encode().toUri();

       try {
           ClientHttpRequest request = requestFactory.createRequest(uri, HttpMethod.GET);
           request.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
           ClientHttpResponse response = request.execute();
           HttpStatus status = response.getStatusCode();
           String json = readBodyAsString(response);
           return new ResponseEntity<>(json, status);
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.append("{\"message\": \"").append(ioe.getMessage()).append("\"}");
           return new ResponseEntity<>(sb.toString(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
       }
   }
```

This works really well for all get requests that have any number of paths.

Problem is the

```
HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE
```

Only grabs the paths of a given URL and not the Query Params

So if this controller gets a request with /api/path/path/path it works but if it gets /api/path/path/path?query=1?search=2 for example it will only grab /api/path/path/path and then the subsequent request will fail since it required query params.

How can I get the entire path of the wild card match to include any queryParams that might be here

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple just needed to use req.getQueryString() to get all the query params as a string.

Also important to note that I needed to pass the query as a .query() on the UriComponentsBuilder so that it gets encoded properly.

```
   URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(targetHost)
           .path(uriString)
           .query(queryParams)
           .build().normalize().encode().toUri();
```